# Log4j configuration: how to use environment variable in yaml configuration file log4j2.yaml

Tags: java, tomcat, yaml, log4j2

I'm trying to configure the log system of an application running on Tomcat, and I would like it to log under $CATALINA_HOME/logs without hardcoding the path.
In doing so I created this configuration file log4j2.yaml:

```
Configuration:
  name: Default
  Properties:
    Property:
      name: log-path
      value: "/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/logs"
  Appenders:
    Console:
      name: Console_Appender
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
    File:
      name: File_Appender
      fileName: ${log-path}/logfile.log
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
  Loggers:
    Root:
      level: error
      AppenderRef:
        - ref: Console_Appender
    Logger:
      - name: myname
        level: debug
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: File_Appender
```

and this actually works. I would like to substitute /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.15 with the environment variable CATALINA_HOME. What is the syntax to achieve this?

Comment: You include the [tag:YAML] tag, but there is nothing in YAML that can handle environment variables.

Comment: So this https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#Environment_Lookup is only achievable in xml configuration but it is impossible to do something similar in yaml?

Comment: That is not necessarily the case. It is just not something that is inherent to YAML. It would need to be implemented on top of YAML (in `log4j2`, in `tomcat` or any other) by either processing the datastructure after the YAML parser loaded it, or by processing the text before handling it to the YAML parser.

Comment: That is in contrast to a question like "Can I define a value in YAML and reuse it in multiple places in a YAML document?" Such a question has an answer within YAML (using an anchor and aliases).

Answer (score 3):

In case you or anybody is still looking for this

for env properties set like

```
 -DYourSystemProperies=/home/winner
```

you can specify this variable using

```
RollingFile:
       - name: RollingFile_Appender
         fileName: ${sys:YourSystemProperies}/abc.log
```